# OpenSolaris/OpenIndiana drive full, cannot boot

Tags: zfs, opensolaris

While downloading my drive became full and now it is non booting.

I installed a new drive in the workstation then installed exactly the same OS.

I am now trying to go about a simple way of accessing my full drive and getting my data  which is in the root directory `/root/virtualbox`.
Since both systems have the same rpool structure, what can I do to mount the secondary drive without conflicts?

I have cloned the drive and am using the clone for this. There is more than one way to go about this looking for suggestions.

I am thinking of cloning the drive to a bigger drive,  maybe stretch the partition from 1tb drive to 2tb drive.

Not sure yet if this is a solution. On a ZFS level, what is a good practice?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! and thank you for posting. Getting good answers requires a clear and useful question which is [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) , [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and contains sufficient details to provide you with a good solution. - Please improve your question to address those points or run the risk of leaving your problem unresolved and/or having your question closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the faulty pool specifying an alternate mount point with the `-R` option:

```
zpool import -R /a device
```